# extend backbone class and override only one field of an object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone class (that is itself extended) that i want to extend. The class has a options object.
In the extended class i want to override one of the field of the options object.

```
BaseClass = Backbone.View.extend({

    options: {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        wantToOverride: {...}
    },
    ...

    events: {
        'mousedown' : 'onMouseDown'
    }
}


DerivedClass = BaseClass.extend({?????})
```

what is the best way to achieve this?

Furthermore, say in the new class i want to add an event, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent `options` will be available on `DerivedClass.__super__.options`, and `constructor` runs before anything else, so you can combine objects as you see fit in that method. For example:

```
DerivedClass = BaseClass.extend({
  options: {
    wantToOverride: 'foo'
  },
  events: {
    'click': 'onClick'
  },
  constructor: function() {
    var parentOptions = this.__super__.options,
        parentEvents = this.__super__.events;

    this.options = _.extend({}, parentOptions, this.options);
    this.events = _.extend({}, parentEvents, this.events);
  }
});
```

If this is going to happen with many classes, you may want to set up a base class with this constructor and have everything inherit from it.

Comment: javascript is complaining __ super __ is undefined